How to ensure data accuracy in spring boot data Jpa?
Recently, I am working on spring boot project. This is basically a backend project. I have repository class in where I have used a complex query that take header id and give single row output.
Repository interface:
package com.springboot.project.leavemonitoringapp.repository;

import com.springboot.project.leavemonitoringapp.model.LeaveApproval;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.Query;
import org.springframework.data.repository.query.Param;

import java.util.List;

public interface LeaveApprovalRepository extends JpaRepository<LeaveApproval, Long> {
    @Query(value = "SELECT ROWNUM SRL_NUM,\n" +
            "        REPORT_HEADER_ID,\n" +
            "        NTF_RESPONDER,\n" +
            "        CASE\n" +
            "           WHEN APPROVER_NAME IS NULL THEN NTF_RESPONDER\n" +
            "           ELSE APPROVER_NAME\n" +
            "        END\n" +
            "           APPROVER_NAME,\n" +
            "        APPROVER_ACTION,\n" +
            "        NTF_NOTE NOTE,\n" +
            "        ACTION_DATE\n" +
            "   FROM                                                                     --\n" +
            "       (                                                                    --\n" +
            "        SELECT  SRL_NUM,\n" +
            "                REPORT_HEADER_ID,\n" +
            "                ACTION_DATE,\n" +
            "                NTF_RESPONDER,\n" +
            "                APPROVER_NAME,\n" +
            "                APPROVER_ACTION,\n" +
            "                NTF_NOTE\n" +
            "           FROM                                                             --\n" +
            "               (  SELECT X.SRL_NUM SRL_NUM,\n" +
            "               X.EXPENSE_REPORT_HDR_ID REPORT_HEADER_ID,\n" +
            "                         X.NTF_RESPONDER,\n" +
            "                         CASE\n" +
            "                            WHEN PPF.FULL_NAME IS NULL\n" +
            "                            THEN\n" +
            "                               (SELECT DISPLAY_NAME\n" +
            "                                  FROM APPS.WF_ROLES\n" +
            "                                 WHERE NAME = X.NTF_RESPONDER)\n" +
            "                            ELSE\n" +
            "                               PPF.FULL_NAME\n" +
            "                         END\n" +
            "                            AS APPROVER_NAME,\n" +
            "                         INITCAP (X.NTF_ACTION) AS APPROVER_ACTION,\n" +
            "                         REPLACE (REPLACE (X.NTF_NOTE, CHR (13), ' '),\n" +
            "                                  CHR (10),\n" +
            "                                  '')\n" +
            "                            AS NTF_NOTE,\n" +
            "                         TO_CHAR (X.CREATION_DATE, 'DD-MON-RR HH24:MI')\n" +
            "                            AS ACTION_DATE\n" +
            "                    FROM                          --xxssgil_er_approval_hist x\n" +
            "                        XXSSGIL.XXSSGIL_APPROVAL_HISTORYS_VV X,\n" +
            "                         APPS.PER_ALL_PEOPLE_F PPF\n" +
            "                   WHERE X.EMPLOYEE_ID = PPF.PERSON_ID(+)\n" +
            "                         AND TRUNC (X.CREATION_DATE) BETWEEN PPF.EFFECTIVE_START_DATE(+)\n" +
            "                                                         AND PPF.EFFECTIVE_END_DATE(+)\n" +
            "                         AND X.EXPENSE_REPORT_HDR_ID = :L_INVOICE_ID\n" +
            "                ORDER BY X.SRL_NUM)\n" +
            "        UNION ALL\n" +
            "        (SELECT SRL_NUM,\n" +
            "        REPORT_HEADER_ID,\n" +
            "                ACTION_DATE,\n" +
            "                NTF_RESPONDER,\n" +
            "                APPROVER_NAME,\n" +
            "                APPROVER_ACTION,\n" +
            "                NTF_NOTE\n" +
            "           FROM (SELECT 0 AS SRL_NUM,\n" +
            "                        H.REPORT_HEADER_ID,\n" +
            "                       WUR.USER_NAME AS NTF_RESPONDER,\n" +
            "                        (SELECT PAPF.FULL_NAME\n" +
            "                           FROM APPS.PER_ALL_PEOPLE_F PAPF,\n" +
            "                                APPS.PER_ALL_ASSIGNMENTS_F PAAF\n" +
            "                          WHERE     1 = 1\n" +
            "                                AND PAPF.BUSINESS_GROUP_ID = '84'\n" +
            "                                AND PAPF.EMPLOYEE_NUMBER = WUR.USER_NAME --'3023'\n" +
            "                                AND PAPF.PERSON_ID = PAAF.PERSON_ID\n" +
            "                                AND TRUNC (SYSDATE) BETWEEN PAPF.EFFECTIVE_START_DATE\n" +
            "                                                        AND PAPF.EFFECTIVE_END_DATE\n" +
            "                                AND TRUNC (SYSDATE) BETWEEN PAAF.EFFECTIVE_START_DATE\n" +
            "                                                        AND PAAF.EFFECTIVE_END_DATE)\n" +
            "                           AS APPROVER_NAME,\n" +
            "                        'Pending' AS APPROVER_ACTION,\n" +
            "                        '' AS NTF_NOTE,\n" +
            "                        '' AS ACTION_DATE\n" +
            "                   FROM APPS.XXSSGIL_APPROVAL_LV_HDR H,\n" +
            "                        APPS.XXSSGIL_APPROVAL_LV_LINE L,\n" +
            "                        APPS.WF_USER_ROLES WUR,\n" +
            "                        APPS.WF_NOTIFICATIONS N\n" +
            "                  WHERE     1 = 1\n" +
            "                        AND H.REPORT_HEADER_ID = :L_INVOICE_ID\n" +
            "                        AND WUR.ROLE_NAME = N.TO_USER\n" +
            "                        AND H.WF_ITEM_KEY = N.ITEM_KEY\n" +
            "                        AND L.REPORT_HEADER_ID = H.REPORT_HEADER_ID\n" +
            "                        AND N.STATUS = 'OPEN'\n" +
            "                        AND H.STATUS_FLG = 'In-Process')))\n" +
            "                        order by SRL_NUM desc\n" +
            "            FETCH FIRST 1 ROW ONLY",nativeQuery = true)
    List<LeaveApproval> findLeaveApprovalRecord(@Param("L_INVOICE_ID") String headerId); //here L_INVOICE_ID is replace by report header id
}

Service class:
@Service
public class AttendanceLeaveService {
    @Autowired
    private AttendanceLeaveRepository attendanceLeaveRepository;
    @Autowired
    private LeaveApprovalRepository leaveApprovalRepository;
    @Autowired
    private LeaveIssueRepository leaveIssueRepository;
    @Autowired
    private PFLoanRepository pfLoanRepository;

    public List<AttendanceLeave> getAttendanceLeaveRecord(String status){
        return attendanceLeaveRepository.findAttendanceLeaveRecord("");
    }

    public List<LeaveApproval> getLeaveApprovalRecord(String headerId){
        return leaveApprovalRepository.findLeaveApprovalRecord(headerId);
    }
    public PFLoan getPFInfo(String empId){
        return pfLoanRepository.findPFInfo("",empId);
    }

    public Map<String,List<LeaveApproval>> getLeaveIssue(){
        List<String> headerIdList = List.of("17524","17527","17529");
        Map<String,List<LeaveApproval>> unsolvedLeaves = new HashMap<>();
        for (String headerId : headerIdList){
            List<LeaveApproval> leaveApproval = getLeaveApprovalRecord(headerId);
            unsolvedLeaves.put(headerId,leaveApproval);
        }
        return unsolvedLeaves;
    }

Here, there is getLeaveIssue() in where there is a list of header id and a for loop that take a header id and pass it by below line
List<LeaveApproval> leaveApproval = getLeaveApprovalRecord(headerId);

This function is ok for each header id with passing single value by a list(List.of("17524")). But it not working properly with passing multiple values(List.of("17524","17527","17529")). To find out I have debug a lot and found that inaccurate output.
like below
 {
    "17524": [
    {
    "serialNumber": 3,
    "headerId": "17524",
    "responderName": "4939",
    "approverName": "Mr. ABDUS SALAM (GM-Distribution)",
    "approverAction": "Approved",
    "note": null,
    "actionDate": "24-APR-24 11:29"
    }
    ],
    "17527": [
    {
    "serialNumber": 2,
    "headerId": "17527",
    "responderName": "5284",
    "approverName": "Mr. MD. MOTIUR RAHMAN (COO-Operations)",
    "approverAction": "Approved",
    "note": null,
    "actionDate": "24-APR-24 15:58"
    }
    ],
    "17529": [
    {
    "serialNumber": 3,
    "headerId": "17524",
    "responderName": "4939",
    "approverName": "Mr. ABDUS SALAM (GM-Distribution)",
    "approverAction": "Approved",
    "note": null,
    "actionDate": "24-APR-24 11:29"
    }
    ]
    }

Here we can see the value with 1st header id is repeated for last output.
Why it happen?
How to fix?

This question would really benefit if it had a [mre]

I have found out a way from where I get my expected result. Initially I had used to fetch data using Jpa repository. I proved that Jpa repository save 1st iteration result in its cache and it delivered this same result others iterations repeatedly.
Finally I used java JDBC instead of Jpa repository and got expected result.
